# CSS Main menu won't hover due to hyperlink underneath

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net

I have some CSS which I found and use for my main menu on my website which works fine. However, when a message notification hyperlink image is visible which is located underneath where the menu hovers, the hovering menu quickly disappears when you move the mouse as it is picking up the hyperlink underneath. I have worked out that pointer-events:none; will make the message notification not clickable and then the hovering menu works, but the notification hyperlink needs to be clickable.

I've tried z-index in places but there's containers and other things to deal with so I thought a possible solution would be to somehow apply pointer-events:none to the notifications Div when hovering takes place?

I use vb.net for my coding.

```
 <div style="float:left; margin-left:338px; margin-top:-30px; " runat="server" id="notificationsDiv"><asp:HyperLink ID="hypNotifications" runat="server" Visible="false" NavigateUrl="~/Account/messageList.aspx"><asp:Image ID="imgNotifications" runat="server" Visible="false" ImageAlign="Middle" ImageUrl="~/files/images/icons/yesmessages.png" /></asp:HyperLink></div>
```

Main menu CSS in seperate Layout.CSS file

```
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border- 
 box;margin:0;padding:0; }
.clr{clear:both;}

#mainNav {
  background-color:#8BC28B;
  font-size:0;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
}

#mainNav ul {font-size:11px; }
#mainNav i {font-size:3em;}
#mainNav li {display:inline-block; height:inherit;}

#mainNav a {
    color:#fff;
    font-family:'Open Sans', Tahoma, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    display:block;
    height:inherit;
    margin:0;
    padding:0.75em 0.75em;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#mainNav a:hover {
    background-color:#DF7764; transition: background .25s ease; 
}

#mainNav li .sub-menu {
    background-color:#900;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity .75s;
    width:100%;
    z-index:10;
}

#mainNav li:hover .sub-menu {
    left:0px;
    opacity:1;
}

#mainNav .sub-menu i {font-size:1em;}

#mainNav .sub-menu a {
    height:3em; line-height:3em;
    padding:0 1em; 
    height:inherit;
    width:100%;
} 

#mainNav .sub-menu a:hover {background-color:#f60;}
```

Comment: User 'Alto' has a similar problem [SO62054308: How could I prevent the div from blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62054308/2015909). Does that help? Please post a [reprex] otherwise, thanks!

Comment: I learned a little bit from that link so thanks. However, the problem here is slightly different. I have z-index:10 on the main menu and have set the notifications div to -1 but then the hover works but hyperlink notification never does.