# How could I prevent the div from blocking the dropdown?

Tags: html, css

There's this dropdown from W3Schools that seems to work after my edits<sup>Links: 1</sup>
Unfortunately, another `<div>` element blocks it and the `.dropdown:hover` doesn't work.<sup>2</sup>

This happened when I positioned the dropdown icon nicely inside a different div<sup>3</sup>,
and it also results from the blocking div having to be to the left of the dropdown.

**(I'm trying to make the hover work: the dropdown options should appear when you hover over the menu icon.)**

---

First I put the width to 75%.
But oddly it didn't work (I still kept it)

I've tried changing the z-index of everything:

- Blocking div / paragraph: -2
- Container including dropdown: -1
- Dropdown: 1

After awhile I saw that z-index only applied to elements with
`css position: absolute, relative, fixed, sticky`

But putting the `position: relative` didn't work. <sup>†</sup>

I also found out about `pointer-events: none;` from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738984/css-hover-passes-through-elements-to-activate-hover-on-covered-element) but sadly nothing. <sup>†</sup>

In the Chrome Developer Tools there was an orange margin covering the dropdown.

I set the margin to 0, and made the border of the div and paragraph visible.
Somehow the dropdown still doesn't open. I don't understand why it doesn't - and the Chrome Console doesn't show any orange anymore.

Also I messed with the CSS display property. By default it's a block element, which takes up the whole width.<sup>4</sup>
Inline makes height and width properties have no effect. And most of the others are based off of block and inline (or table) - but I still tried (and they failed) them.

Unfortunately all of these fail quite silently, except when I turned the blocking div into a span element, in which everything collapsed.

---

Code snippet (*Instructions:* <sup>5</sup>)

```js
function menu(text) {
  // respond
  console.log(`Click success: ${text}`)
}

// 4 seconds to hover over the menu icon
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("storyDiv").style.marginTop = "10%"
}, 4000)
```

```css
#gameMenu {
  color: red;
}

#storyDiv {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: auto; /* Makes it scrollable if the text is too big */
  border: 1px solid blue;
  z-index: -2;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#story {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
  pointer-events: none;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}


/* Edited dropdown from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp */

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdownContent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdownContent button {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdownContent {
  display: block;
}


/* End of dropdown */

#infoContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 76%;
  width: 23%;
  border: 1px solid dodgerblue;
  z-index: -1;
  /* [Result] text in the top-right corner blocks the menu,
     Also for the demonstartion */
  margin-top: 10%;
}

#playerInfo {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Menu symbol -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>

<body>
  <div id='storyDiv'>
    <p id='story'>
      With i (color), em, ul, and li tags. As well as <br>br, and enough to expand the bottom-border enough so that it's visually below the menu icon, blocking it.<br>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id='infoContainer'>
    <div class='dropdown'>
      <span class="material-icons" id='gameMenu'>menu</span>
      <div class='dropdownContent'>
        <button onClick='menu("Instructions")'> Instructions </button>
        <button onClick='menu("Settings")'> Settings </button>
        <button onClick='menu("Credits")'> Credits </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="playerInfo">
      <p>Another div with other stuff in it.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

1. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp <s>(not neccessary to understand this)</s>
2. The dropdown is in a div, so originally I thought it was blocked by it, or one of the other elements in the div.
3. It was overlapping with (the border of the container div), which is visible for aesthetic reasons. No removing. Well, originally the icon was in the top left corner, but that was obtrusive of the adventure story in the `<p>` I was talking about.
4. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp
5. When "run" is clicked hover over the red menu icon. The dropdown works. Take your mouse off and wait until the box pops down next to the menu div. Put your mouse back over the dropdown. Now it doesn't work

† I tried all (as far as I know) the combinations for (this). Just the `<p>`, only `<div>`, or both, doesn't work.

**Other notes:**
I just want to make the hover work, and I don't want the content to change position.

---

Comment: I'm very lost regarding what you want to achieve. Can you send a picture of how your end goal is or perhaps a website using this design already?

Comment: You really need to understand what a 'stacking context' is, when to use 'relative' and 'absolute' positioning and how to use `z-index` in that respect. The answer given, however, does the trick. Not trying to be smug, but regarding  *1. .... (not neccessary to understand this)*: think again....

Comment: Add `body { outline: 1px dashed }` to your CSS and you will see that you actually positioned `#infoContainer` under `<body>` by using `z-index: -1` and therefore blocked access to the menu as `body { ...z-index: 0... }` is default in HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `z-index = -1` in `#infoContainer` and it shall work.

```
    #infoContainer {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      left: 76%;
      width: 23%;
      border: 1px solid dodgerblue;
      /* z-index: -1; */ /* REMOVE */
      /* [Result] text in the top-right corner blocks the menu,
         Also for the demonstartion */
      margin-top: 10%;
    }
```

```js
function menu(text) {
  // respond
  console.log(`Click success: ${text}`)
}

// 4 seconds to hover over the menu icon
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("storyDiv").style.marginTop = "10%"
}, 4000)
```

```css
#gameMenu {
  color: red;
}

#storyDiv {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: auto; /* Makes it scrollable if the text is too big */
  border: 1px solid blue;
  z-index: -2;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#story {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
  pointer-events: none;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}


/* Edited dropdown from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp */

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdownContent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdownContent button {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdownContent {
  display: block;
}


/* End of dropdown */

#infoContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 76%;
  width: 23%;
  border: 1px solid dodgerblue;
  /* z-index: -1; */ /* REMOVE */
  /* [Result] text in the top-right corner blocks the menu,
     Also for the demonstartion */
  margin-top: 10%;
}

#playerInfo {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Menu symbol -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>

<body>
  <div id='storyDiv'>
    <p id='story'>
      With i (color), em, ul, and li tags. As well as <br>br, and enough to expand the bottom-border enough so that it's visually below the menu icon, blocking it.<br>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id='infoContainer'>
    <div class='dropdown'>
      <span class="material-icons" id='gameMenu'>menu</span>
      <div class='dropdownContent'>
        <button onClick='menu("Instructions")'> Instructions </button>
        <button onClick='menu("Settings")'> Settings </button>
        <button onClick='menu("Credits")'> Credits </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="playerInfo">
      <p>Another div with other stuff in it.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```